# Auto fill formula

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create an Excel macro that can expand my formula on a column with different sizes.

I currently have 2 Pivot Tables and at the end of each one I have created a column of concatenated values.
Eg:
 - Table 1: Cols D:I , concatenated col J
   First Cell with formula is J12 (`=CONCATENATE(D12;E12;F12;G12)`)
 - Table 2: Cols O:T , concatenated col U
   First Cell with formula is U12 (same as before)

I want to be able to press a button after refreshing the tables that will delete cols J and U and fill them with the formula again according to the tables' ranges.

I have created tried codes like
`Range("J12:M" & LastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE ... "`
but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put a concatenated formula through VBA in a given range, something like this could be of use:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = 42
    Range("J12:M" & lastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())," & _
                                                    "INDIRECT(""E""&ROW()))"

End Sub
```

There are a few tricky parts:

- use `ROW()` to get the row;
- use `.Formula` to force the English version of the Excel formula;
- use `""` to escape the single `"`;
- use `INDIRECT()` to get the value of the cell;